# SQL Assistance: Query issues

Tags: sql, sql-server

I keep running into problems. What I need to get is the top 3 Countries witht he highest AVG rate.

```
SELECT TOP 3 
   Country, AVG(AverageRate) AS 'AverageRate'
FROM 
   dbo.CountryOrders
WHERE 
   OrderDate BETWEEN '2011-01-01' AND '2011-12-31'
GROUP BY 
   Country
ORDER BY 
   'AverageRate' DESC;
GO
```

Comment: Is `TOP 3` even supported by your database?

Comment: In sql server 2005/2008 `ORDER BY` cant see aliases.

Comment: Your date format suggests MySQL, your `dbo.` and TOP N suggests SQL Server. What RDBMS is this for?

Comment: Or use column index: `ORDER by 2`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
SELECT  TOP 3 Country, AVG(AverageRate) AS 'AverageRate'
FROM dbo.CountryOrders
WHERE OrderDate BETWEEN '2011-01-01' AND '2011-12-31'
GROUP BY Country
ORDER BY AVG(AverageRate) DESC;
GO
```

Comment: This answered the question! Thanks to you and @Gordon

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the single quotes are `AverageRate`.  Only use single quotes for string and date constants.  You don't need them here, so just remove them:

```
SELECT  TOP 3 Country, AVG(AverageRate) AS AverageRate
FROM dbo.CountryOrders
WHERE OrderDate BETWEEN '2011-01-01' AND '2011-12-31'
GROUP BY Country
ORDER BY AverageRate DESC;
```

You query failed to order by you are ordering by a constant value, the string 'AverageRate'.  If you need to escape an identifier, use double quotes or square braces (Sybase and SQL Server-specific).